# Why the return statement doesn't work inside if statement?

Tags: java, string, return

When I try to return this way, the compiler throws an error.

> Compile Message Main.java:15: error: missing return statement
> }
> ^ 1 error Exit Status 1

```
public class Main {
    static String distances(int x, int y, int z) {
        int distanceA = Math.abs(z-x);
        int distanceB = Math.abs(z-y);
        
        if(distanceB > distanceA) { 
            return "distance A";
        }
        else if(distanceB < distanceA) {
            return "distance B";
        }       
        else if(distanceB == distanceA) {
            return "distance C";
        }
    }
}
```

*REST OF THE CODE.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turn the last **else if** 'else if(distanceB == distanceA)' into **else** and it should be work